# Alamofire 5.*: Decode and handle error parsed json validation response using jsonDecodable

Tags: json, swift, error-handling, alamofire, response

I'm trying to create post request to the server using Alamofire:

```
static func callAndDecode<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> Future<T> {
  return Future(operation: { completion in
      AF.request(route)
        .responseDecodable(decoder: decoder, completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
            switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    completion(.success(value))
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(error)
            }
        })
  })
}
```

Everything is fine, I can call server and I'm getting the success response with the data, also I can get an error response.

But the problem is when for example I'm trying to register user, I'm sending parameters, but if email already exists, I'm getting an error with 422 status code with validation messages for every parameter that I sent and it failed, in JSON format.

response.data, after the error happens:

```
{
  "first_name" : [
      "The first name field is required."
  ],
  "email" : [
      "The email has already been taken."
  ]
}
```

How can I return that validation data throw the completion handler, so if I call some URL and it throws an error (422) with JSON data, how to return that data with the error object?

Now I only have `error.localizedDescription`, I don't have access to the data that I got from the server. So maybe I have to serialize response somehow or to create my own DataResponse, that is the question?

Is there a method to do this or I have to go back and use Swift URL sessions?

I tried to create a custom response serializer but I didn't succeed, can anyone help me?

Here is my implementation of this service:

```
class AuthService {
  static func login(email: String, password: String) -> Future<Auth> {
     return RequestAPI.callAndDecode(route: APIRouter.login(email: email, password: password))
  }

  static func signUp(parameters: [String: Any]) -> Future<ModuleRoot<User>> {
     return RequestAPI.callAndDecode(route: APIRouter.users(parameters: parameters))
  }
}

//MARK: Functions
func signUp() {
    AuthService.signUp(parameters: [
        "id": 1,
        "first_name":  self.firstName,
        "last_name":  self.lastName,
        "email":  self.email,
        "password": self.password
    ]).execute(onSuccess: { result in
        print("_____________________________")
        print(result)
        self.firstName = ""
        self.lastName = ""
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.showLogin = true;
    }, onFailure: {error in
        if error.asAFError?.responseCode == 422 {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription )
            //todo: handle error validation
        }
    })
}
```

I'm using Alamofire, PromisedFuture, and SwiftyJSON frameworks,...

This is the latest try to do this because I'm trying to find a solution all day, it's not that I didn't try and just ask here.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What's the issue here? Is it that you need to return a different type in the error case?

Comment: Hi, the issue is that I need to return this data that I got here when error happened:

["first_name": "The email has already been taken."]